# SilverStripe - Add values from multiple DataObjects

Tags: php, silverstripe

I have a `DataObject` with multiple entries. Each entry has a variable named `Sum`.

I would like to add all the `Sum` variables together with a function on the related page.

How do I do this?

Comment: A lot of this can be found in the API doc http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataList.html

Comment: thank you, i'll have a look at it before aksing the next question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
public function getTotalSum() {
    return MyDataObject::get()->sum('Sum');
}
```